# How do I center a Component in a JPanel without using BorderLayout? - Java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, centering

I think, that you can center a `Component` (for Example a `JButton`) in a `JPanel`, using the `BorderLayout`:

```
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
panel.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

But than the `JButton` takes up all the space in the `JPanel`.

Is it for example possible to use another `LayoutManager`, or is there an even easyer way to do center the `JButton`?

I think, `button.setAlignmentX(JButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT)` doesn't work.

Comment: See  https://www.java-forums.org/new-java/51332-center-button-jpanel-help-please.html

Comment: `GridBagLayout`

Answer (score 0):

I guess with most tasks it's just a matter of personal choice/your boss's order if you're using a Layout manager rather than the others. There are some Layout managers that can accomplish quite every requirement, such as GridBadLayout, but i personally think that in most situation they're not the best choice since they might end up overcomplicating things. For this specific task i would go with a BoxLayout https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html

And would code something like:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CenteredButton extends JFrame {

    public CenteredButton() {
        Container pane = getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("Button1");
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));

        panel.add(button);

        pane.add(panel);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CenteredButton();
    }
}
```

As you may notice, resizing the button's dimension will not change the fact that it sticks in the middle of the frame.

PS: developers opinions are mostly enthusiastic about http://www.miglayout.com/ and https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/. Both of these, in my opinion, are easier to manage than GridBagLayout